# Unable to locate element using xpath from Auto suggest dropdown

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to locate an element from an autosuggestion list using xpath but getting InvalidSelectorException. Below is my code:-

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='EngagementCode']")).sendKeys("111");
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//[@id='typeahead-5-5946-option-0']/a"))).click();
```

Also please suggest How can I find it using different method if possible.

[Please find HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeKn9.png)

```
 <ul id="typeahead-5-5946" class="dropdown-menu ng-isolate-scope" ng-show="isOpen() && !moveInProgress" ng-style="{top: position().top+'px', left: position().left+'px'}" style="display: block; top: 34px; left: 15px;" role="listbox" aria-hidden="false" typeahead-popup="" matches="matches" active="activeIdx" select="select(activeIdx)" move-in-progress="moveInProgress" query="query" position="position">
<!-- ngRepeat: match in matches track by $index -->
<li id="typeahead-5-5946-option-0" class="ng-scope active" ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index)" role="option">
<a class="ng-binding ng-scope" href="" tabindex="-1" ng-bind-html="match.label | typeaheadHighlight:query">
xxx
<strong>111</strong>
x  - xxx services_xxx
</a>
</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: match in matches track by $index -->
```

Comment: your xpath looks ok. Only check if the selector returning multiple elements

Comment: Sorry but I am new to this How am I going to check that?

Comment: https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html . You can check your xpath validity here.

Comment: Please provide the html as code, not as an image.

Comment: In the HTML snippet you provided there is no element with ID 'EngagementCode'.

Comment: HTML which I have shared is of the auto suggest drop down which opens when I enter Engagement Code in a field and I am trying to select first element of that dropdown list which is at .//[@id='typeahead-5-5946-option-0']/a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about your locators, as I can not see any element with id 'engagement code'. I yo can provide more coverage of HTML, then it will be easier to answer. 
I would suggest to use Firefox plugin Firebug to inspect elements and Firepath to validate your xpath.
I have tried Google page autosuggestion box. Giving the code snippet below, See if this can help you.

```
 WebElement searchBox= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='lst-ib']"));
    System.out.println("searchBox.isDisplayed(): "+searchBox.isDisplayed());
    searchBox.sendKeys("Seleni");

    System.out.println("search value: "+searchBox.getAttribute("value"));
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='sbqs_c']")));

    List<WebElement> autoTextList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='sbqs_c']"));

    System.out.println("List size: "+autoTextList.size());
    for(WebElement listItem : autoTextList){
        System.out.println("List item: "+listItem.getText());
        if(listItem.getText().equals("selenium webdriver")) {
            listItem.click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To **`click(select)`** the `autosuggestion` **`111`**, you can use the following block of code :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement elem = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[@class='ng-scope active']/a[@class='ng-binding ng-scope']/strong")));
elem.click();
```